# mod_rewrite and iPhone redirect

Tags: iphone, .htaccess

I've been working on the iPhone version of an already existing application.

We use some rewrite rules for better SEO and to make it easier for visitors.
eg. http://www.site.com/index.php?job=4ef187d6e66b7 is rewritten as http://www.site.com/jobs/4ef187d6e66b7

We also use a rule to redirect all iPhone users to our mobile site, as following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/
RewriteRule .* /m/ [R]
```

The mobile site is just located at www.site.com/m/

But when I head over to http://www.site.com/jobs/4ef187d6e66b7, I'm getting redirected to http://www.site.com/m/?job=4ef187d6e66b7, while that should be http://www.site.com/m/jobs/4ef187d6e66b7

Is there a way to redirect people and still keep some of the existing rules?
I also tried adding this rule, but that didn't work

```
RewriteRule ^m/jobs/([^/]+) m/index.php?job=$1 [NC]
```

This is the full .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^jobs/([^/]+) index.php?job=$1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/
RewriteRule .* /m/ [R]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the iPhone redirect first, and then mark it 'last'. That way, the mobile redirect will have priority over the other redirects.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/
RewriteRule (.*) /m/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(m/|)jobs/([^/]+) index.php?job=$2 [NC]
```

Also be sure that you include the original path in the redirect (as shown on the third line).

The last rewrite rule will match `/m/jobs/xxx` as well as `/jobs/xxx`.

Comment: That seemed to work at first, the url is not rewritten correctly.

But form some reason it doesn't seem to work: _The requested URL /m/jobs/4ef9a591edc33 was not found on this server._

Comment: That means that the rewrite IS working! The iPhone is now redirected to **/m/...**. You should now handle the `/m/...` URL correctly. If you want to catch in in the last rewrite rule, you should modify it accordingly. I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks, the rewrite is working indeed.
I'm just running into another problem now, when I head over to http://www.site.com/jobs/4ef9a591edc33, I'm being redirected to http://www.site.com/m/index.php?job=4ef9a591edc33

Which is the correct url, but it should show up as http://www.site.com/m/jobs/4ef9a591edc33

Comment: Are you using the `L` (last) directive in the RewriteRule (see line 3)?